# std::regex with ifstream - not working

Tags: c++, regex, c++11, ifstream

I was playing around with std::regex and noticed that it doesn't work if the string is from an ifstream for some reason.. if I uncoment the the ifstream code, the regex stops working; even though, the string value is the same.

```
/* c++ -Wc++11-extensions -stdlib=libc++ -std=c++11 powerball.cpp -o powerball
 example file content..
Draw Date   WB1 WB2 WB3 WB4 WB5 PB  PP
09/25/2013  49  07  17  53  02  23
09/21/2013  58  54  45  17  12  13
09/18/2013  07  10  35  32  22  19
 */
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    string line = "09/25/2013  49  07  17  53  02  23";

    regex pbrx("^(\\S+)\\s+(\\S+)\\s+(\\S+)\\s+(\\S+)\\s+(\\S+)\\s+(\\S+)\\s+(\\S+).*");

    /* doesn't work if I do this - even though the content is the same
    ifstream ifs("pb-winnums-text.txt");
    getline(ifs,line);
    getline(ifs,line);
    cout << line << endl;*/

    smatch matches;
    cout << "m.. " << regex_match(line, pbrx) << endl;
    if (!regex_match(line, matches, pbrx)) {
        cout << "NOPE!" << endl;
    }

    for (size_t m = 0; m < matches.size(); m++) {
        cout << m << ": " << matches[m].str() << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: This just means that, contrary to your assumption, the content is not in fact the same. Uncomment `getline`-related code, add this line: `cout << (line == "09/25/2013  49  07  17  53  02  23") << endl;` What does it print?

Comment: Thanks!  You are correct!  However, ".*" should take care of trailing WhiteSpace - shouldn't it?  Anyway, changing ".*" to "\\s+" caused it to work.  There is a "  \r" trailing each line in the file; but I thought the ".*" would cover it.

Comment: @user2827725 `.*` matches carriage returns, newlines and so on if you specify the flag singleline (not multiline, mind you, but it can also be called dotall (make the "dot match all"). I'm not sure how to set it in c++11 though.

Comment: @Jerry: per Ecma-262 15.10.2.8, `.` matches all characters except <LF>, <CR>, <LS>, or <PS>; this is regardless of flags. `multiline` flag only affects the behavior of `^` and `$` (namely, whether they match at beginning or end of line, or only at the first and last characters of the string). In C++, this is controlled by `match_not_bol` and similar flags, which you can pass to `regex_match` or `regex_search`.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I specified **not to use multiline** because there is often confusion between singleline and multiline.

Comment: @Jerry: You said, and I quote: "`.*` matches carriage returns, newlines and so on". This is false. It does not, whether in JavaScript or in C++ (at least in ECMAScript mode; I didn't study other modes closely), regardless of any flags specified.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik You should quote properly, I said: "`.*` matches carriage returns, newlines and so on **if you specify the flag singleline**"

Comment: @Jerry: once again, with feeling: it does not, I repeat **not**, do that under any circumstances, regardless of any flags specified or omitted.